# In Angular Js ,ng-repeat is Not working. See the below code snippet

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use `ng-repeat` but it is not working , please help. I have coded it correctly as per my understanding. The data is returning from the AJAX call, but data binding is an issue

```js
 var app = angular.module('App', []);
    app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $http, $window, $timeout) {


       
    function getQueryParam(param) {
        var result = window.location.search.match(
            new RegExp("(\\?|&)" + param + "(\\[\\])?=([^&]*)")
        );

        return result ? result[3] : false;
    }
    console.log(getQueryParam("Param1"));
    console.log(getQueryParam("Param2"));

    var Period = getQueryParam('Param1');
    $scope.Period = Period.replace(/%20/g, " ");

    var User_Name = getQueryParam('Param2');
    $scope.User_Name = User_Name.replace(/%20/g, " ").replace('/', '');

    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        $scope.GetLowControlDetails();
    });

   $scope.GetLowControlDetails = function () {
 var url = '@Url.Action("GetLowControlDetails", "Home")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                data: { "Period": $scope.Period, "User_Name": $scope.User_Name,"Control":"Low" },
                success: function (data) {
                   console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                   
                  $scope.LowControl_List = JSON.parse(data);
                  
                  },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("qeqeqeeeqeqeqdeddwd");
                }
            });
        
    }

    });
```

```css
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```html
    <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller">

       

        
       @*<div class="row" ng-show="LowControl_List.length>0">*@

            <div class="col-12 month-field">
                <div class="row week-field head">
                    <div class="col-1">Functions</div>
                    <div class="col-1">Risk Category</div>
                    <div class="col-1">Risk Event</div>
                    <div class="col-4">Control Description</div>
                    <div class="col-1">Control Code</div>
                    <div class="col-3">Comment</div>
                    <div class="col-1">Commented By</div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 month-field">
                 
                    <div class="row week-field" ng-repeat="row in LowControl_List">
                        <div class="col-0" ng-hide="true">{{row.ROW_NUM}}</div>
                        <div class="col-1">{{row.Function}}</div>
                        <div class="col-1">{{row.Risk_Category}}</div>
                        <div class="col-1">{{row.Risk_Event}}</div>
                        <div class="col-4">{{row.Control_Description}}</div>
                        <div class="col-2">{{row.Controls_Code}}</div>
                      


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

     
        </div>
```

0: {ROW_NUM: "38", Function: "Finance", Risk_Category: "Operational Risks", Risk_Event: "Fraud Risk", Control_Description: "Conduct routine and surprise checks including 3rd party confirmations where applicable.", …}
1: {ROW_NUM: "108", Function: "Legal", Risk_Category: "Regulatory & Compliance Risks", Risk_Event: "Other Regulatory Risk", Control_Description: "A) Track and report breaches to Trade Sanctions po…ances of alleged breaches to the Sanctions Policy", …}
2: {ROW_NUM: "110", Function: "Legal", Risk_Category: "Regulatory & Compliance Risks", Risk_Event: "Data Privacy", Control_Description: "1) Adopt necessary policies that address key globa…asures to avoid breaches of data protection laws ", …}
3: {ROW_NUM: "152", Function: "Plantation", Risk_Category: "Agricultural Risks", Risk_Event: "Agronomy/GAP (Good Agricultural Practices) Risk", Control_Description: "Adequate process to monitor Yield of each Farm against the budget or plan.", …}
4: {ROW_NUM: "33", Function: "Finance", Risk_Category: "Operational Risks", Risk_Event: "Stock risk", Control_Description: "Confirm valuation is done correctly keeping in min…lescence and slow moving / non-moving inventories", …}
5: {ROW_NUM: "47", Function: "Finance", Risk_Category: "Operational Risks", Risk_Event: "Fraud Risk", Control_Description: "Banking Controls : (a) Opening of bank account fol… documentation are performed (system or manual). ", …}

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: can you please format the code properly ? or use stackoverflow code template or share jsfiddle?

Comment: Why do you have `'@Url.Action("GetLowControlDetails", "Home")'` in javascript the code ?

Comment: its to call the method to get dataset from Database.Thats working only binding is an issue :(

Comment: Please `console.log` the response - `JSON.parse(data)` and provide in the post or provide the sample response from the service

Comment: Console.log is appended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206514/discussion-between-trendy-cuz-and-aditya-bhave).

Comment: what error you are getting ? @Trendycuz

Comment: Please try 1) Remove document.ready, call function directly from controller. 2)Declare function before you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
    app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $http, $window, $timeout) {



    function getQueryParam(param) {
        var result = window.location.search.match(
            new RegExp("(\\?|&)" + param + "(\\[\\])?=([^&]*)")
        );

        return result ? result[3] : false;
    }
    console.log(getQueryParam("Param1"));
    console.log(getQueryParam("Param2"));

    var Period = getQueryParam('Param1');
    $scope.Period = Period.replace(/%20/g, " ");

    var User_Name = getQueryParam('Param2');
    $scope.User_Name = User_Name.replace(/%20/g, " ").replace('/', '');



   $scope.GetLowControlDetails = function () {
 var url = '@Url.Action("GetLowControlDetails", "Home")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                data: { "Period": $scope.Period, "User_Name": $scope.User_Name,"Control":"Low" },
                success: function (data) {
                   console.log(JSON.parse(data));

                  $scope.LowControl_List = JSON.parse(data);

                  },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("qeqeqeeeqeqeqdeddwd");
                }
            });

    }


        $scope.GetLowControlDetails();


    });
```